# Need help on this Linq GroupBy query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am producing a report which will display daily usage over time.

I have the activity and the days coming through, however I would love some direction on how to achieve the following:

- Day's grouped (so a single entry of 12/02/2018 should exist)
- An Activity column summing entries for the day (eg. 35 for 12/02/2018)
- A new column representing `RecordCount` (which is the amount of entries found per day, Eg. 12/02/2018 would display 2.)

**What I have so far**

```
// Engagement - Daily activity over time
PageStatistics.Where(x => x.Status == 1)
    .GroupBy(x => new { Day = x.CreatedAt.Date, x.AppID })
    .Select(x => new { Day = x.Key.Day, Activity = x.Count() })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Day)
    .ToList()
    .Select(x => new { Day = x.Day.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), Activity = x.Activity })
```

Thanks a lot.

**Update**

I am looking for Day, Activity(Total Count across all AppIDs) and RecordCount(Distinct AppID entries).

[image]

Comment: Why are you grouping by AppId if you are just going to group it again by day? am i reading your problem correctly, or do you want to do another group?

Comment: @MichaelRandall I was just trying things :) Attempting to bring AppID into the equation, as this is what controls my "RecordCount" split I am after. Happy for all and any direction.

Comment: I think I know what you're trying to do but let me know if I'm off base. If you pull AppId out of the GroupBy you could get RecordCount by doing x.Select(r => r.AppId).Disinct().Count().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me you are already doing what you desire.

Given

```
public class Page
{
   public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
   public int Status { get; set; }
   public int AppID { get; set; }
}
```

Group by `CreatedAt` and `AppId`

```
var result = pageStatistics.Where(x => x.Status == 1)
           .GroupBy(
              x => new
                 {
                    Day = x.CreatedAt.Date,
                    x.AppID
                 })
           .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key.Day)
           .Select(
              x => new
                 {
                    Day = x.Key.Day.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                    AppID = x.Key.AppID,
                    RecordCount = x.Count()
                 })
           .ToList();
```

I.e you are getting a list of all app activity on different Days

***Note*** : i just put `AppID = x.Key.AppID`, to show you your groups

---

However, if you want group by `CreatedAt` (agnostic of `AppId`)

```
var result = pageStatistics.Where(x => x.Status == 1)
           .GroupBy(x => x.CreatedAt.Date)
           .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key.Date)
           .Select(
              x => new
                 {
                    Day = x.Key.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                    RecordCount = x.Count()
                 })
           .ToList();
```

---

**Update**

These are the *Driods* you are looking for

```
var result = pageStatistics.Where(x => x.Status == 1)
              .GroupBy(
                    x => new
                       {
                          CreatedAt = x.CreatedAt.Date,
                          x.AppID
                       })
              .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key.CreatedAt)
              .Select(
                    x => new
                       {
                          x.Key.CreatedAt,
                          Activity = x.Count()
                       })
              .GroupBy(x => x.CreatedAt)
              .Select(
                    x => new
                    {
                       Day = x.Key.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                       Activity = x.Sum(y => y.Activity),
                       RecordCount = x.Count()
                    })
              .ToList();
```

Comment: I have just been testing your query, thanks. However looking at the Select list, I am looking for Day, Activity(Total Count across all AppIDs) and RecordCount(Distinct AppID entries). Unfortunately this won't result in this. Eg. 28/02/2018 | 35 | 2. Would be a desired row result.

Comment: After the update, it looks like the question is answered.

Comment: @MichaelRandall Your answer checks out perfectly thanks. As I received more activity that day, the counters are now higher. But for the 12th my raw data looks like this (with new AppID column included for ref) http://prntscr.com/iexcsv totally 12 rows and a total of 444 Activity. Which correctly matches your Linq output of 12 and 444 - http://prntscr.com/iexd10 :) So thank you very much for your effort!

Comment: @GONeale glad i could help

Comment: I must say, query run time is 16.715s so I'm just trying to get to the bottom of that now. Perhaps indexing issues on my DB; do you see any obvious culprits? Thanks

Comment: @GONeale indexing is probalby the key

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding following shall suffice:

```
PageStatistics.Where(x => x.Status == 1)
    .GroupBy(x => new { Day = x.CreatedAt.Date })
    .Select(x => new { Date = x.Key.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), 
                       Activity = x.Sum(y => y.AppID), 
                       Record = x.Count()});
```

Reviewing the questions, I have created the following Linqpad code, which produce the result as expected. I haven't appended `OrderBy` or extra `Select`, you can massage the data on need basis. Point remains since AppId is required for Sum and Count calculations, so we don't use it in the Grouping logic and use the value projection for the Sum (activity) and Record (Count) values. Also note, in the Select statement projection is a IGrouping collection, which can be further processed using Linq `Select`, `SelectMany`

**Code**

```
void Main()
{
    List<Page> PageStatistics = new List<UserQuery.Page>();

    PageStatistics.Add(new Page(new DateTime(2018,02,12),3));
    PageStatistics.Add(new Page(new DateTime(2018,02,12),32));
    PageStatistics.Add(new Page(new DateTime(2018,02,11),20));
    PageStatistics.Add(new Page(new DateTime(2018,02,11),44));
    PageStatistics.Add(new Page(new DateTime(2018,02,11),20));
    PageStatistics.Add(new Page(new DateTime(2018,02,11),2));
    PageStatistics.Add(new Page(new DateTime(2018,02,11),1));
    PageStatistics.Add(new Page(new DateTime(2018,02,10),22));
    PageStatistics.Add(new Page(new DateTime(2018,02,10),2));
    PageStatistics.Add(new Page(new DateTime(2018,02,10),20));
    PageStatistics.Add(new Page(new DateTime(2018,02,10),10));


    var result  = 
    PageStatistics.Where(x => x.Status == 1)
    .GroupBy(x => new { Day = x.CreatedAt.Date })
    .Select(x => new { Date = x.Key.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), 
                       Activity = x.Sum(y => y.AppID), 
                       Record = x.Count()});

    result.Dump();
}

public class Page
{
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public int AppID { get; set; }

    public Page(DateTime c, int a)
    {
        CreatedAt = c;
        AppID = a;  
        Status = 1;
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry Mrinal, but your answer had sum()'d AppID which is not what I was after.

Comment: @GONeale I have realized, that your requirement is different from, what I understood. You need grouping first by Date and AppId, then by Date to achieve the final result as in the accepted solution.